# How to not get an error when pasting data into a sheet with formulas already in it?

Tags: excel

I need a little help understanding how I can simply cut and paste data (multiple cells without formulas) from a CSV doc into a xls template without causing errors on the formulas already in the xls sheet.

to put it another way, When I paste the raw data (no formulas in this data) into the xl sheet template, I have to rebuild the formulas in the template sheet to get them to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers
Glenn

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Redesign your spreadsheet so that the formulas are outside of the pasted range. If you paste into a range of cells, existing content, be it values or formulas, will be overwritten, even if the CSV contains blank cell content. That's how it works.

Comment: formulas are outside the pasted range

Comment: In that case, edit your question and give an example of the formula before and after you paste the csv. We're trying to help but you must provide better information.